# What is `_doc` inside mongoose (console.log show the same results with it and without)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I would like to have an answer what exactly `._doc` mean in mongoose or mongodb. and why destructuring/`...` show an error in `console.log` but works fine in return statement.

Next 2 lines return the same objects so why it's there and what `._doc` is doing 
console.log(event); // return the same objects
console.log(event._doc); // return the same objects

```
`events: () => {
   return Event.find()
     .then(events => {
       return events.map(event => {
         console.log(event); // return the same objects
         console.log(event._doc); // return the same objects
         console.log(...event); /* Graphql say "Found non-callable @@iterator" but later, on return I'm using destructuring without any errors why ? */
           return {
              ...event._doc, 
               _id: event._doc._id.toString(), 
               date: new Date(event._doc.date).toISOString(),
               creator: user.bind(this, event._doc.creator)
                };
            })
        })`
```

It's how `console.log(event); or console.log(event._doc);` looks like

```
`{ _id: 5c1c6d928debd345a54de4ce,
  title: ' Test',
  description: 'Test',
  price: 26.99,
  date: 2018-12-21T04:35:30.672Z,
  creator: 5c1c699bc1f1423c0047d2f1,
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 5c1d8cde6efd7f02832aa2fa,
  title: 'Test 2',
  description: 'another description',
  price: 23.22,
  date: 2018-12-22T01:01:18.735Z,
  creator: 5c1c699bc1f1423c0047d2f1,
  __v: 0 }
{ _id: 5c1d8d6f6f51b802fc32ab22,
  title: 'Test 3',
  description: 'another description 3',
  price: 123.22,
  date: 2018-12-22T01:03:43.543Z,
  creator: 5c1c699bc1f1423c0047d2f1,
  __v: 0 }`
```

So it's even not an array why I need a `...` in return ?
I'm following this code in tutorial but doesn't understand these 2 things so I'll highly appreciate any useful answer. 
I'm using: `Mongo, MongoDb and GraphQl`
Thank you.

Comment: After all, it's an internal property (that's what the underscore means) and your code should never interact with it.

Answer (score 3):

The `_doc` field lets you access the "raw" document directly, which was delivered through the mongodb driver, bypassing mongoose. This is also why you might get confusing results using `console.log`.

If you just log an mongoose element, the output can look very similar to the output of _doc, since mongoose has a toString() method that will output only the actual datapoints and not all the helperfunctions like (.save(),.update()...).

Check https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose#driver-access for more info